# Model structures on groupoids

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, homotopy-theory, higher-category-theory, model-categories

Let me preface by saying that I'm very inexperienced with model categories. I was thinking about the following example, and I'm now wondering whether it fits into the theory of model stuctures:
Consider the category of Lie groupoids, $Gpd$, with smooth homomorphisms as morphisms. I want to think about the following example. Let $X$ be a smooth manifold, and $G$ a Lie group. Since $G$ only has one object, and $X$ only has identity arrows, $Hom(X,G)$ is simply a point. However, we might suspect that the 'right answer' should be principal $G$-bundles over $X$. There are 2 ways to achieve this.

1) Choose a good cover $\mathcal{U} = \{U_{i} \}$ for $X$, and replace $X$ with a Morita equivalent groupoid $C(\mathcal{U})$, whose space of objects is the disjoint union of the open sets $U_{i}$, whose morphism space is the disjoint union of the double intersections $U_{i} \cap U_{j}$, and where an arrow $x \in U_{i} \cap U_{j}$ goes from the point $x \in U_{j}$ to the point $x \in U_{i}$. A morphism in $Hom(C(\mathcal{U}), G)$ consists of the data of smooth maps $g_{ij} : U_{i} \cap U_{j} \to G$, which satisfy $g_{ij} g_{jk} = g_{ik}$; in other words, Cech data for a principal bundle.

2) Replace $G$ with an equivalent groupoid, whose space of objects consists of the 'space of all $G$-torsors'. In order to avoid issues with having too many objects, we might take the space of objects to be something like an infinite grassmanian, or more generally a geometric realization of $BG$. In this case, we again find that morphisms in $Hom(X,BG)$ give principal bundles by pulling back a universal bundle.

(In the above two constructions, I am ignoring questions of equivalences of maps, although I think they should enter in as homotopy equivalences in the model category.)

So my question is whether there is a model structure on $Gpd$, such that $C(\mathcal{U})$ is a cofibrant replacement for $X$, the groupoid in part 2 is a fibrant replacement for $G$, and where Morita/essential equivalences of groupoids are weak equivalences?
From what I understand, model structures allow one to present higher categories, and indeed, by inverting the essential equivalences in the category $Gpd$, one obtains a $2$-category, which embeds into the $2$-category of stacks on the site of smooth manifolds. In this $2$-category, $Hom(X,G)$ is indeed the groupoid of principal $G$-bundles. Are there perhaps good references, which explain this example?

Finally, I am also wondering if (and how) this is at all related to this paper of Kapranov

> *Injective resolutions of BG and derived moduli spaces of local systems*, Journal of Pure and Applied Algebra **155** Issues 2–3 (2001) pp 167–179 [10.1016/S0022-4049(99)00109-7](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-4049%2899%2900109-7), arXiv:[alg-geom/971002](https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9710027)

about injective resolutions of $BG$? In his case, I guess he would be considering $Hom(\pi_{1}(X), G)$, and I'm not sure I understand why $G$ needs to be resolved.

Comment: I feel like the main problem will be to actually make sense of the construction in (2). This construction should be your fibrant replacement, so it is definitely important, but don't you need some infinite dimensional manifolds to make sense of this in general ? Can you really find a nice category Lie groupoids in which this construction can always be performed ?

Comment: This is something weaker than a model structure that would do the (1), something more like a category of fibrant objects, but there are still concerns about the lack of all limits in the category of manifolds. The second one I've never seen. If all you want to do is model the localisation of Gpd by Morita equivalences as a higher category, why not just do it as a bicategory (which is all you need)?

Comment: @DavidRoberts I'm less interested in modelling the localization (which I'm practice I like to do using groupoid bibundles), than using this example to gain intuition about using (co)fribrant replacements to resolve objects. For example, if I didn't know what answer I was supposed to get, then how would I know to do 1) or 2)?

Comment: @unknownymous I would not use Lie groupoids, in that case, but internal groupoids in a better ambient category. For instance, this paper has a nice treatment http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/15/3/15-03abs.html but it doesn't apply to topological or to Lie groupoids (I tried!)

Comment: Note that in the Kapranov paper he is using an injective resolution by simplicial dg-manifolds, not just in the category of (nerves of) Lie groupoids, so it's a bit more involved than just a model structure on the category of Lie groupoids.